# Split one TIFF file into multiple TIFF files using VRT file

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, vrt

I have a VRT file like below

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="10801" rasterYSize="10801">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="2,1">GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform> -1.2100013888888888e+02,  2.7777777777777778e-04,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  3.7000138888888891e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -2.7777777777777778e-04</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test1.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="7200" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test2.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="3600" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test3.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test4.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="3600" yOff="7200" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test5.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="3600" yOff="3600" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test6.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="3600" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test7.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="7200" yOff="7200" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test8.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="7200" yOff="3600" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Test9.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="3601" RasterYSize="3601" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="3601" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
      <DstRect xOff="7200" yOff="0" xSize="3601" ySize="3601" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

I also have one big TIFF file that I want to split based on this VRT file. Is it possible to do so?
I couldn't find any rasterio or GDAL commands that will do the same.